# Reassemble files from TCP stream using PcapDotNet in C#

Tags: c#, windows, tcp, stream, winpcap

How can I reassemble files from TCP stream using `PcapDotNet` in C#?

Comment: [**Asking the same question twice**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122505/how-to-reassemble-files-from-tcp-stream-using-pcapdotnet-in-c-sharp) will definitely not help you get answers, more likely a question ban.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We're here to help with **specific** programming related issues/questions, so you need to show your research and attempts in solving the problem. Please refer to [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you open to other programming languages such as c++?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the project `PacketDotNet.Connections` https://github.com/chmorgan/packetnet-connections

It's specifically designed to your type of use case.

---

Another alternative is PcapPlusPlus https://pcapplusplus.github.io/,
see the [TCP Reassembly](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/TcpReassembly#tcp-reassembly) example.